# NULL pointer comparison to zero segfaults

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, comparison

So, I have this piece of C code:

```
226     if (!pair)
227         return;
228     if (!pair->index)
229         free(pair->index);
```

I am running through it with a non-null 'pair' pointer which has a null (0) member 'index'. It works wonderfully, as one might expect. On the other hand, this

```
226     if (!pair)
227         return;
228     if (pair->index!=NULL)
229         free(pair->index);
```

generates a segmentation fault (on line 228, where the if is). It seems weird, since the two should be identical, right? (the second makes even more sense to me than the first, that's why I used it in the first place)

I am fine with just using the negative expression which works, but I want to understand why the second segfaults. Any ideas? :)

(I am building with gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 )

Thanks!

Comment: May `pair->index` point to illegal or freed address?

Comment: When the program crashes, what's the value of `pair` and `pair->index`? Is it possible that you already called `free` on `pair->index`?

Comment: The comparisons are not identical `!p` means `p == NULL`.

Comment: Or maybe `pair->index` doesn't point to something returned by `malloc`? How do you initialize `pair->index`?

Comment: Haha, I guess it's time to get some rest, you are right. So the problem is in calling "free" on the pointer and not in the if.

Comment: pair->index = 0; it's not supposed to point to anything in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to note, standard c already has the null check built into `free` so you ought not to check this again yourself.

In your first snippet, the line `if (!pair->index) free(pair->index);` is benign probably due to a typo: `free` is only called if the `pair->index` is null, and `free` will pass over that as I've already said. You have an errant `!` in your `if` statement. So your program is unlikely to crash there. (Technically it *might* if `pair->index` is uninitialised since the use of an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour in c).

There is no problem in the second snippet you present, unless `pair->index` is not pointing to memory given to you by a prior call to `malloc`, `calloc` etc. If you are sure you own the memory at `pair->index` then the problem is due to a heap corruption or an undefined behaviour construct elsewhere in your program.

Comment: (gdb) p pair
$1 = (JSONPair *) 0x603010
(gdb) p pair->index
$2 = 0x0

Comment: Well, I found my problem... Apparently index was not zero in the first place, but was pointing to some invalid pointer. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Yup. In c your variables are not initialised on declaration. Furthermore to use an uninitialised one is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I didn't notice my (!) mistake and that mislead me to believe there's some crazy behavior in pointer dereferencing when using the equal operator... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Indeed. c is riddled with tricky corners. Undefined behaviour is often only a few keystrokes away. But it is devilishly fast and compiles very quickly since the grammar is so simple.